# My Flashdrive isn't working because I deleted system volume information

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive

I accidentally deleted my System Volume Information on my Flashdrive and now Windows can't recognize it.
It always asks me to scan the drive before but it still isn't working.
I don't know how to do it but I have my important files and documents on the drive.
Please can you help me?

Comment: Hopefully, you have a backup of those files, since you accidentally also deleted those important files

Comment: Deleting 'System Volume Information' has _no_ effect, Windows just recreates it. Your problem is another one; maybe you deleted all your files too?